# Formulário Receber em 2 tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho este codigo para receber dados em duas tabelas diferentes. 
Mas apenas a primeira tabela esta a receber dados. A segunda continua em branco.
É possivel este codigo funcionar desta maneira?

```
if(($query=mysql_query($sqlinsert)) and ($query2=mysql_query($sqlinsert2))){
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_funcoes VALUES(0,'"....)";     
$sqlinsert2 = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador VALUES(0,NULL,NULL,'o."',....)";

}
```

Quando o erro ocorre, retorna a seguinte mensagem:

```
Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: A segunda consulta retorna erro? é melhor vc tirar os dois `mysql_query` do if e adicionar `or die(mysql_error())` no final. Cuidado também com `and`e `&&` pois ambos tem prioridades diferentes [Operadores lógicos](http://br2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: Estranha esse verificação. O resto do seu código deve fazer sentido esse teste. Mas recomendo por um OR DIE do final de cada query e ler o retorno.

Comment: Se a primeira query está sendo executada com sucesso, significa que a condição está sendo válida. O SQL da sua segunda query é exatamente esse?

Comment: `$sqlinsert` e `$sqlinsert2`não deveriam estar antes do `if` ?

Comment: Exacto. copiei o codigo antigo. 
o $sqlinsert e $sqlinsert2 estão antes do if

Comment: @user3253195, tentou executar uma consulta por vez? qual a mensagem de erro retornada?

Comment: "If(($query=mysql_query($sqlinsert)) and ($query2=mysql_query($sqlinsert2))){ 
}"

Com tanta alteração a testar agora da-me erro no sitio onde coloco o "or die (mysql_error())"

Comment: assim, sem o `if`, `mysql_query('select.....') or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 1):

O Problema ocorre por causa que já existe um id `0` como chave primária em sua tabela, por isso ele não permite que você insira outro igual, pelo fato de que chaves primárias não podem ser dupliacadas, para resolver você teria que fazer o seguinte:

```php
if(($query=mysql_query($sqlinsert)) and ($query2=mysql_query($sqlinsert2))){
  $sqlmax = "select max(nomedocampoID) from tb_funcoes";
  $sqlmax2 = "select max(nomedocampoID) from tb_detalhe_trabalhador";
  $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_funcoes VALUES(".$sqlmax.",'"....)";     
  $sqlinsert2 = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador VALUES(".$sqlmax2.",NULL,NULL,'o."',....)";
}
```

Seria nada mais que pegar o ultimo ID(Chave primária) que existe em suas tabelas, para que nenhum ID seja duplicado e sempre auto incrementando.

**Nota: não esqueca de pegar o nome do campo que contém o ID(chave primaria) e substituir pelo meu "nomedocampoID" que coloquei acima.**